# Is there a more efficient way to resolve this "one to many" circular reference?

Tags: sql-server

In our ERP database, there is 1 table for products called `PRODUCTS`, which contains both kits and single SKU product information, and a table called `PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS` that contain the relationships between kit SKUs and their components.

In the PRODUCT table, each kit has a `KIT_ID` on the parent SKU row and the `PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS` table lists each component `PRODUCT_ID` from the `PRODUCTS` table and the kit id of the parent SKU associated with it.

What I wanted was a list of all the SKUs of components associated with a parent SKU, both of which would be selected from the same column on the `PRODUCTS` table.

This was the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT   Parent.[PRODUCT_SKU] AS KitParent,
         Child.[PRODUCT_SKU] AS ChildSKU
FROM     [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS]
JOIN     (
          SELECT [PRODUCT_ID],[PRODUCT_SKU]
          FROM   [PRODUCTS]
         ) AS Child 
ON       Child.[PRODUCT_ID] = [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS].[PRODUCT_ID]
JOIN     (
          SELECT [PRODUCT_ID], [PRODUCT_SKU],[KIT_ID]
          FROM   [PRODUCTS]
          WHERE  [KIT_ID] IS NOT NULL
          AND    [KIT_ID] != 0
         ) AS Parent 
ON       Parent.[KIT_ID] = [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS].[KIT_ID]
ORDER BY Parent.[PRODUCT_SKU];
```

I'm a bit of a newbie and was wondering if there was a better way to accomplish this, for instance, without running two sub-queries on the PRODUCTS table.

Comment: Please add tables schema. And if possible sample data and the desired result.

Comment: ++version of SQL Server being used.

Comment: If you think that is complicated be happy that you do not have kits that can ontain other kits ;) Hierarcies in TSQL are... ah, lets say not nice.

Comment: Have you looked at [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server) at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your current table schema:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS 
> (
>    PRODUCT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
>    PRODUCT_SKU INT,
>    KIT_ID INT
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS
> (
>     KIT_ID INT,
>     PRODUCT_ID INT REFERENCES PRODUCTS(PRODUCT_ID),
>
>     PRIMARY KEY (KIT_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES 
> (1, 10, 1), (2, 20, 0), (3, 30, 0), (4, 40, 2),
> (5, 50, 0), (6, 60, 0), (7, 70, 0), (8, 80, 0);
>
> INSERT INTO PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS VALUES
> (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 6), -- KIT_ID(1) HOLDS PRODUCT_ID(2, 3, 6)
> (2, 5), (2, 7);         -- KIT_ID(2) HOLDS PRODUCT_ID(5, 7)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 13 rows affected
> ```

You can get it by selecting all products with KIT_ID <> 0 (Parent rows) and then use CROSS APPLY to select all child rows that match parent KIT_ID.

> ```
> SELECT      P.PRODUCT_SKU AS PARENT_SKU,
>             CHILDS.PRODUCT_SKU AS CHILD_SKU
> FROM        PRODUCTS P
> CROSS APPLY (SELECT P2.PRODUCT_SKU
>              FROM   PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS PKI
>              JOIN   PRODUCTS P2
>              ON     P2.PRODUCT_ID = PKI.PRODUCT_ID
>              WHERE  PKI.KIT_ID = P.KIT_ID) CHILDS
> WHERE        COALESCE(KIT_ID, 0) <> 0
> ORDER BY     P.PRODUCT_SKU; 
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> PARENT_SKU | CHILD_SKU
> ---------: | --------:
>         10 |        20
>         10 |        30
>         10 |        60
>         40 |        50
>         40 |        70
> ```

Your current query:

> ```
> SELECT   Parent.[PRODUCT_SKU] AS KitParent,
>          Child.[PRODUCT_SKU] AS ChildSKU
> FROM     [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS]
> JOIN     (
>           SELECT [PRODUCT_ID], [PRODUCT_SKU]
>           FROM   [PRODUCTS]
>          ) AS Child 
> ON       Child.[PRODUCT_ID] = [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS].[PRODUCT_ID]
> JOIN     (
>           SELECT [PRODUCT_ID], [PRODUCT_SKU], [KIT_ID]
>           FROM   [PRODUCTS]
>           WHERE  [KIT_ID] IS NOT NULL
>           AND    [KIT_ID] != 0
>          ) AS Parent 
> ON       Parent.[KIT_ID] = [PRODUCT_KIT_ITEMS].[KIT_ID]
> ORDER BY Parent.[PRODUCT_SKU];
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> KitParent | ChildSKU
> --------: | -------:
>        10 |       20
>        10 |       30
>        10 |       60
>        40 |       50
>        40 |       70
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7aab4beb644eaad1ce261ec06d293646)*